# NodeJS - Loop through range as string

Tags: node.js, math.js

I'm trying to loop through a range of numbers in NodeJS, but not by using integers, by using a string.

For example, I want to loop through from 000000 to 500000. Ie. 000001, 000002, all the way to 500000. When percieved as an integer, NodeJS will just go 1, 2, all the way up to 500000. I want to keep if so the number always has 6 digits and loops through every possible number.

Edit: I need it to loop through like 000001, 000002, ..., 000010, ... , 000100, ... , 001000, ... , 010000, ... , 100000, ... , 500000. Filling in every number in between though

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using a relatively new version of node you can use `string.padStart()`:

```
for(var i = 0; i <= 500000; i++) {
    str = i.toString().padStart(6, 0)
    // 000001, etc
}
```

More docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart

Comment: Works pefect with Node 8.6. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Iterating through the number as usual but padding 0's before it.

```
function pad (str, max) {
  str = str.toString();
  return str.length < max ? pad("0" + str, max) : str;
}

for(var i = 0; i <= 500000; i++) {
  console.log(pad("6", i)) ;
}
```

Comment: That just constantly adds 0's. I need it to be no less than 6 digits, and no more than 6 digits, whereas your method keeps adding 0's, therefore increasing the amount of digits every time. I need it to loop through like 000001, 000002, ..., 000010, ... , 000100, ... , 001000, ... , 010000, ... , 100000, ... , 500000. Filling in every number in between though